# matching event date column to todays date

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to get records that match with todays date(not time) but the times are different so no match? Should I use substring on the e.eventdate?

```
  List<Time> time = db.TimeSet.Where(e
=> e.Employee.Username == username && 
                e.EventDate == DateTime.Today).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx

You should be able to do:

```
db.TimeSet.Where(e => e.EventDate.Day == DateTime.Today.Day && e.EventDate.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && e.EventDate.Year == DateTime.Today.Year)
```

Comment: Apparently you are using a Nullable<DateTime> (guessing from your comments). Than EventDate.Value.Day would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property on EventDate?

Something like

```
e.EventDate.Date == DateTime.Today
```

Comment: Is EventDate an actual DateTime?

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

Answer (score 0):

Try this

List time = db.TimeSet.Where(e
=> e.Employee.Username == username && 
                e.EventDate.Date == DateTime.Today.Date).ToList();

Comment: Please be aware that there is no need to use DateTime.Today.Date as Today is already without the time portion. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx